# How to convert comma separated string to list that contains comma in items in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string for items separated by comma. Each item is surrounded by quotes ("), but the items can also contain commas (,). So using `split(',')` creates problems.

How can I split this text properly in Python?

### An example of such string

`"coffee", "water, hot"`

### What I want to achieve

`["coffee", "water, hot"]`

Comment: Can you show a few more examples of what you're looking for?

Comment: @Dennis Sure, but before that I updated to question with the result I want to achieve. Does that help?

Comment: @Dennis Now that I see example and the result visually, I think I can just add [] to string and convert to list? Haha I'll try that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Comment: @Kaneki21 Thank you for the suggestion. It splits the items into individual lists and doesn't have conflicting delimiter in individual items. So unfortunately, that's not the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ast

s = '"coffee", "water, hot"'

result = ast.literal_eval(f'[{s}]')

print(result)
```

Comment: Update: This doesn't work when the text is not surrounded by quotes ("). Gives `invalid syntax`.

Comment: @stackyname It's pretty easy to simply check for quotes before doing the eval. This is the most complete answer of them all in my opinion.

Comment: @user56700 thank you. And what do you suggest to do if there is no quotes?

Comment: @stackyname The same as always: Look up which format was used and then use a parser for that format. This time I actually didn't fully, as I'm hacking the brackets around it and guessing that it's otherwise appropriate for `literal_eval`, but I was displeased by the many previous answers doing imho  worse hacks. Anyway, this question says *"Each item is surrounded by quotes"*, so if you want to ask about about a different format, I suggest to ask another question.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah you're right. It's different topic. Just wanted to know if there is a solution with this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can split on separators that contain more than one character. `'"coffee", "water, hot"'.split('", "')` gives `['"coffee','water, hot"']`. From there you can remove the initial and terminal quote mark.

Comment: I thought and tried this actually but it seemed like an a little bit ugly solution and gave the vibe that it may ruin things when dealing with lots of data haha. Thank you though, if I can't find something better, I'll go with this.

Comment: If `"coffee"` were `", "`, you'd split incorrectly. Admittedly that seems unlikely, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re

s = '"coffee", "water, hot"'
re.findall('"(.*?)"', s) # ['coffee', 'water, hot']
```

Comment: It's not uncommon for strings to contain quotes, usually escaped like `\"`, which you'd match.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost use csv for this:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO
sio = StringIO()
sio.write('"coffee", "water, hot"')
sio.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(sio)
print(next(reader))
# Prints ['coffee', ' "water', ' hot"']
```

The problem is that there is a space before the opening quote of "water, hot".  If you replace `'", "'` with `","`, then csv will work, and you will get `['coffee', 'water, hot']`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I defined a function 'del_quote' to remove unnecessary quotes and spaces.
Then I split it taking '",' as a separator. then the result was mapped to remove quotes then converted into list.

```
def del_quote(s):
return s.replace('"','').strip()

x='"coffee", "water, hot"'
result=list(map(del_quote,x.split('",')))
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
string = '"coffee", "water, hot"'

stringList = string.split("'")

string = stringList[0]

print(string)
```